# Having trouble accessing and referring to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, hashmap, set

I'm trying to write a program that handles the storing of students and corresponding subjects, but am relatively new to Java's Lists and am having trouble getting the class to store and output the students and subjects. So far I can get it to store a student and class but will not take multiple, or only returns the most recent one added.

```
private static Map<String, Set<String>> cohort = new HashMap<~>();

public static void signOn(String class, String student) {
    Set<String> studentSet = new HashSet<String>();
    studentSet.add(student);
    cohort.put(class, studentSet);
}

public static Map<String, Set<String>> getCohort() {
    return cohort;
}
```

When calling `getCohort()` I am trying to get it to return all students that have signed on, but it is only returning the most recent student added in. I'm not sure if I am missing something simple but I just can't seem to get it right, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in `signOn` when you are adding a new student, you are creating a new Set, adding one student to it and then overrides any Set that was already there. This means that you will always only have one student there.

What you need to do is to first get the current set of students in a class, and then add your student to them.

Example code:

```
    public static void signOn(String class, String student)
    {
        Set<String> studentSet = cohort.get(class);
        if (studentSet == null) {
            studentSet = new HashSet<String>();
            cohort.put(class, studentSet);
        }
        studentSet.add(student);
    }
```

That should work as studentSet will be a reference to the studentSet that is stored in cohort. I just wrote that from memory so no promises it works in the first try, but that is the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are always creating a new Set, thus overriding the already existing set you saved in cohort.

Try the following:

```
Set<String> studentSet = cohort.get(class);
if(studentSet == null){
  studentSet = new HashSet<String>();
  cohort.put(class, studentSet);
}
studentSet.add(student);
```

As a side note I would like to add that 'class' is properly not the best name for your String variable as it's a Java reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the problem as you are putting `new Set every time` (also when student class is the same), which basically override the old value. So, you need to put a student in the same set if the class is the same. Using Java 8 you can do as follows :-

```
public static void signOn(String cls, String student) {
    cohort.computeIfAbsent(cls, k -> {
        Set<String> studentSet = new HashSet<>();
        studentSet.add(student);
        return set;
    });

    cohort.computeIfPresent(cls, (k, v) -> {
        v.add(student);
        return v;
    });
}
```

*Note: You can't have a variable name `class`, it is a reserved keyword in java.*